# Log in as user/cant not connect to oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
SQL> sqlplus Paris/1234
```

> Unkown command begining "sqlplus..."

I am trying to log in the oracle database with the user name I created. I had created lots of tables there and everything. Service is up running but I can't log in as the user. It keeps telling me it's not connected. Anybody know what I should type here? Thanks!

Comment: Don't get in the bad habit of entering username and password on the same line, it's against the most elementary security rules. Start sqlplus, once it starts type connect Paris, and then you will be prompted for your password. Only enter it then.

Answer (score 3):

SQLPLUS is an executable, not a command, so from within SQLPlus you need something like

```
connect user/password@schema
```

From the operating system prompt, you can use launch SQLPLUS:

```
sqlplus user/password@schema
```

You find more informations in [SQLPlus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#SQPUG013)